# What android devices don't support draw_texture?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

i am developing an android app using OpenGL ES for drawing and i use the draw_texture extension as it's the fastest.

I read you have to query the string to check and see if the drawing method is supported on the phone and degrade gracefully if not. My main concern is, how common is it really to have a device which doesn't support this?

I mean, drawing textured quads (the only method standard in OpenGL) is so slow the game would hardly be enjoyable on these devices.

I'm just curious if it's worth the time to support these devices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an example of Android device lacking the draw_texture extension, but it is highly likely that such devices actually exists in minimal amounts. It's definitely not worthed to dedicate effort in supporting them, but on the other hand it is nearly trivial to switch between drawTex and quads, especially if your code supports rotated sprites.

Comment: Nah, there is no rotating with draw_texture so it's designed to not use rotated sprites. I wish quads weren't soooo slooooww

Comment: How many quads are you drawing to notice slowdown? If properly passed to GL, drawing of 2D quads is very effective and you can pass thousands at a good framerate. Are you using interleaved indexed arrays to pass vertex attributes to GL? Are you minimizing texture switching?